# Django не находит static на всех страницах кроме главной

Tags: python, django

Проект находится на хостинге(в поддержке говорят самому разбираться и поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь друзья) и вы можете найти его по адресу: https://caparolcenterspb.ru 

 
 Все стили, картинки и js на главной появляется, а на других страницах нет. Вы можете посмотреть ошибки прямо в браузере, но на всякий случай оставлю скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а на локально django сервере все работает корректно?

Comment: `python manage.py collectstatic` на сервере соберет всю статику в одну папку. А раздавать ее лучше через nginx.

Comment: на локальном сервере все отлично

Comment: сейчас попробую collectstatic еще раз, на хостинге apache по умолчанию и там нельзя поменять

Comment: пишет, что 0 файлов скопировано и 171 unmodified

Comment: код html покажите где статика прописана, вы видимо написали `src="static/css/main.css"`, а нужно писать `src="/static/css/main.css"`

Comment: Либо пользоваться встроенным {% static 'css/main.css' %}

Comment: Если все это не решает проблему, тогда проверьте в `settings.py` переменную `STATIC_URL`, возможно она указана неправильно.

Comment: Да уже решил проблему, все верно там static_url = '../static/'